# One to one OPTIONAL relationship

Tags: entity-framework, relationship

Traditional EF questions starts with: My models are

```
public class Ingredient
{
    public int IngredientID { get; set; }
    public virtual RequestedIngredient RequestedIngredient { get; set; }
    // other stuff
}

public class RequestedIngredient
{
    [Key]
    string BlahBlahBlah { get; set; }
    public int? IngredientID { get; set; }
    public virtual Ingredient Ingredient { get; set; }
}
```

Somewhere in dbContext...

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Ingredient>()
            .HasOptional<RequestedIngredient>(e => e.RequestedIngredient)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal(e => e.Ingredient)
            .Map(e => e.MapKey("IngredientID"))
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

But I get Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
(195,6) : error 0019: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'IngredientID' was already defined.

If I remove IngredientID from RequestedIngredient, the db will be created just as I want to. But I have no access to IngredientID. How can I set this up to have access to foreign key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not one-to-one relationship. In one-to-one relationship the foreign key must be a primary key. Which is not the case in this example. This is one-to-many, but I assumed that my app will take care of making sure there's only one association.

EF can deal with that using Independent Association. It will create foreign key, hidden from your POCO class. One can specify the name of the column using MapKey as I did. However, because I also created a property called IngredientID, just as the column used with MapKey, the EF has a problem as two properties are mapped to the same column.

So things like that are possible in EF, but you can't use foreign key anymore.